# jump into "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" function unexpected

Tags: iphone

I used an AVAudioPlayer object to control playing multiple music files. I also created an UISlider to control seeking file. But i have a problem when seek the pointer. After seeking, AVAudioPlayer update time correct then jump into "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" function unexpected.
Here is the code that i used :

```
-(void)timeChange
```

{
    _player.currentTime = _timeControl.value;
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer];
}

```
-(void)updateCurrentTimeForPlayer
```

{
    if(_isNeedUpdate == NO) return;
    _timeControl.maximumValue = _player.duration;
}

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, but maybe the audio format doesn't support seeking?

Why the call to `updateCurrentTimeForPlayer`? Where is _isNeedUpdate set? (Why all the underscores?)

Can you add some debug NSLogs to find out what's going on?